# Error 1 Cannot create an instance of the abstract interface - C#

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, mozilla

ok i know what it means, but i dont know how to solve it
here is my interface

```
        public interface nsIDownloadProgressListener
        {
            nsIDOMDocument getDocument();

            void setDocument(nsIDOMDocument doc);

            void OnDownloadStateChange(short state, nsIDownload aDownload);

            void OnStateChange(nsIWebProgress aWebProgress, nsIRequest aRequest, uint                                    
            aStateFlags, object aStatus, nsIDownload aDownload);

            void OnProgressChange(nsIWebProgress WbProgress, nsIRequest aReq, int         
            curSelfProgress, int maxSelfProgress, int curTotalProgress, int 
            maxTotalProgress, nsIDownload aDownload);

            void OnSecurityChange(nsIWebProgress wbProgress, nsIRequest aReq, uint 
            aState, nsIDownload aDownload);
            }
```

here is the class i use to inherit the interface

```
          public class DownloadProgressListenerClass : nsIDownloadProgressListener
          {
              #region nsIDownloadProgressListener Members

              nsIDOMDocument Nothingreturned;

              public nsIDOMDocument getDocument()
              {
                  return Nothingreturned;
              }

              public void setDocument(nsIDOMDocument doc)
              {
              }

              public void OnDownloadStateChange(short state, nsIDownload aDownload)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(aDownload.getId().ToString());
                  OnDownloadStateChange(state, aDownload);
              }

              public void OnStateChange(nsIWebProgress aWebProgress, nsIRequest aRequest, uint aStateFlags, object aStatus, nsIDownload aDownload)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(aDownload.getId().ToString());

              }

              public void OnProgressChange(nsIWebProgress WbProgress, nsIRequest aReq, int curSelfProgress, int maxSelfProgress, int curTotalProgress, int maxTotalProgress, nsIDownload aDownload)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(aDownload.getId().ToString());

              }

              public void OnSecurityChange(nsIWebProgress wbProgress, nsIRequest aReq, uint aState, nsIDownload aDownload)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(aDownload.getId().ToString());

              }

              #endregion nsIDownloadProgressListener Members
          }
```

and then i try to add the listener to DLManager which should work and report progress

```
            DownloadProgressListenerClass DLListener = new DownloadProgressListenerClass();
            DLManager = Xpcom.GetService<nsIDownloadManager>("@mozilla.org/download-manager;1");
            DLManager.addListner(DLListener);
```

is anything wrong with it because it compiles right but when i try to download a file it doesnt trigger anything and it doesnt show the messagebox as its supposed to do

Comment: Why is your question title referring to something which isn't in your question body?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your addListener method is expecting an interface type of 
`nsIDownloadProgressListener` in the code line:
`DLManager.addListner(DLListener);` 
 
If it is so, please change your
 `DownloadProgressListenerClass DLListener = new DownloadProgressListenerClass();` 
into 
 `nsIDownloadProgressListener DLListener = new DownloadProgressListenerClass();` 
If you need explanation, let me know.